# Get directory of a file name in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How to get the directory of a file?

For example, I pass in a string

```
C:\Program Files\nant\bin\nant.exe
```

I want a function that returns me

```
C:\Program Files\nant\bin
```

*I would prefer a built in function that does the job, instead of having manually split the string and exclude the last one.*

**Edit: I am running on Windows**

Comment: You must tell us what environment this is running in to answer this question adequately.

Comment: @Anonymous, very good point.  You would only consider using my answer if you're on Windows and something that supports COM.

Comment: really hoping thats not in a web browser as split() or lastIndexOf would be much better than FileSystemObject

Comment: Why don't you try ```path.dirname("path/to/file")```? It will be adjusted to linux or windows path based on your environment

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I don't know if there is any built in functionality for this, but it's pretty straight forward to get the path.

```
path = path.substring(0,path.lastIndexOf("\\")+1);
```

Comment: Your solution will only work on windows. Linux uses '/' instead. It's better to use an OS independent solution.

Comment: @Nadia the question is about Windows and path separators could be the least of his concerns with portability, we haven't seen the code or know what he's using it for

Comment: I agree to prefer an OS independent solution. Even if it is just for the sake of others coming to this questions. It's a pity, this is the most upvoted answer.

Answer (score 34):

If you use `Node.js`, `path` module is quite handy.

```
path.dirname("/home/workspace/filename.txt") // '/home/workspace/'
```

Comment: i think you mean nodejs, not typescript

Comment: I just wish I could use it with my typescript web page.

Answer (score 19):

Use:

```
var dirname = filename.match(/(.*)[\/\\]/)[1]||'';
```

*The answers that are based on lastIndexOf('/') or lastIndexOf('\') are error prone, because path can be  "c:\aa/bb\cc/dd".
(Matthew Flaschen did took this into account, so my answer is a regex alternative)

Answer (score 14):

There's no perfect solution, because this functionality isn't built-in, and there's no way to get the system file-separator.  You can try:

```
path = path.substring(0, Math.max(path.lastIndexOf("/"), path.lastIndexOf("\\"))); 
alert(path);
```

Answer (score 7):

### Path module has an inbuilt function

Yes, the inbuilt module path has dirname() function, which would do the job for you.

```
const path = require("path");

file_path = "C:\\Program Files\\nant\\bin\\nant.exe" \\windows path
file_path = "C:/Program Files/nant/bin/nant.exe" \\linux path

path.dirname(file_path); \\gets you the folder path based on your OS
```

I see that your path is neither windows nor Linux compatible. Do not hardcode path; instead, take a reference from a path based on your OS.

I generally tackle such situations by creating relative paths using `path.join(__dirname, "..", "assets", "banner.json");`.

This gives me a relative path that works regardless of the OS you are using.

Answer (score 3):

```
function getFileDirectory(filePath) {
  if (filePath.indexOf("/") == -1) { // windows
    return filePath.substring(0, filePath.lastIndexOf('\\'));
  } 
  else { // unix
    return filePath.substring(0, filePath.lastIndexOf('/'));
  }
}
console.assert(getFileDirectory('C:\\Program Files\\nant\\bin\\nant.exe') === 'C:\\Program Files\\nant\\bin');
console.assert(getFileDirectory('/usr/bin/nant') === '/usr/bin');
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to bring this back up but was also looking for a solution without referencing the variable twice.  I came up with the following:

```
var filepath = 'C:\\Program Files\\nant\\bin\\nant.exe';
    // C:\Program Files\nant\bin\nant.exe
var dirpath = filepath.split('\\').reverse().splice(1).reverse().join('\\');
    // C:\Program Files\nant\bin
```

This is a bit of a walk through manipulating a string to array and back but it's clean enough I think.

Answer (score 2):

```
filepath.split("/").slice(0,-1).join("/"); // get dir of filepath
```

1. split string into array delimited by "/"
2. drop the last element of the array (which would be the file name + extension)
3. join the array w/ "/" to generate the directory path

such that

```
"/path/to/test.js".split("/").slice(0,-1).join("/") == "/path/to"
```

Answer (score 1):

And this?

If isn't a program in addressFile, return addressFile

```
function(addressFile) {
    var pos = addressFile.lastIndexOf("/");
    pos = pos != -1 ? pos : addressFile.lastIndexOf("\\");

    if (pos > addressFile.lastIndexOf(".")) {
        return addressFile;
    }

    return addressFile.substring(
        0,
        pos+1
    );
}


console.assert(getFileDirectory('C:\\Program Files\\nant\\bin\\nant.exe') === 'C:\\Program Files\\nant\\bin\\');
console.assert(getFileDirectory('/usr/bin/nant') === '/usr/bin/nant/');
console.assert(getFileDirectory('/usr/thisfolderhaveadot.inhere') === '/usr/');
```

Answer (score -4):

The core Javascript language doesn't provide file/io functions.  However if you're working in a Windows OS you can use the FileSystemObject (ActiveX/COM).

Note:  Don't use this in the client script-side script of a web application though, it's best in other areas such as in Windows script host, or the server side of a web app where you have more control over the platform.

[This page](http://www.yaldex.com/wjscript/sgProgrammingFileSystemObject.htm) provides a good tutorial on how to do this.

Here's a rough example to do what you want:

```
   var fso, targetFilePath,fileObj,folderObj;

   fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

   fileObj = fso.GetFile(targetFilePath);

   folderObj=fileObj.ParentFolder;

   alert(folderObj.Path);
```

Comment: Um... I'm pretty sure the questioner just wanted a simple string manipulation function, not access to the file system!

Comment: Using activeX is not a good idea. This will only work on IE. It will not work on Firefox or any other browser.

Comment: @brianpeiris,  Please read the question carefully.  They say: "instead of having manually split the string and exclude the last one"

Comment: He also said he wanted to use functionality "built-in" to JS, and proprietary ActiveX extensions are anything but.

Comment: @Nadia,  Thats why I clearly say "If you're on Windows".    Also,  I'm well aware how stupid this would be for a normal web app.  However we aare talking about file manipulation so I assume the questions relates to server side code or scripting outside the browser.

Comment: @Matthew, you don't say!  I've explained my rationale in the answer.  In a controlled environment where you know you have access to it, FileSystemObject is a valuable tool.