# How do I read folder names from a list of folders in a directory using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using javascript and want to know how can I read folder names from a list of folders present a directory using some variable. 
I have to later display these names as links in a website.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Do you want some fries with that?

Comment: JavaScript cannot access the local file system ...

Comment: So what have you tried and how does your data look right now?

Comment: @PeeHaa And a cheeseburger for me ! and possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818576/get-directory-of-a-file-name-in-javascript

Comment: Plan B required. You can't get the folders on a client machine with java script.

Comment: @Sirko It is not exactly a website, its a DVD browser's GUI which I am designing using HTML and JAVASCRIPT , I have a directory in which I am working and in that some folders are there, I want to read each folder's name and display it as a link/label in the GUI.

Comment: As said here multiple times, you won't be able to access the file system on the client side. Question is, whether your page is hosted on some kind of (minimal) webserver. Then you may access the filesystem server side.

Comment: You should provide more information about the execution environment of the JavaScript, possible with links. I cannot imagine how a DVD menu works with HTML and JavaScript. As you noticed, most people assumed you will execute the JavaScript from the browser, which is the typical use case. You want something different, consequently you have to provide information about. Otherwise you won't get any answers. We cannot help you if we don't know what's going on. It's still likely though that this DVD thingy does not let you access the file system either.

Comment: No there is no Server involved , it is just a GUI being made for a DVD browser. Can You guys suggest me the alternative for Javascript , which does not require any dependent softwares,etc. and which could read the folder names in the directory?

Comment: @FelixKling , 


Hi,
This is the Javascript code I am using to read folder names in a given directory, but this does not seem to work... can anyone help me with it?


function getFiles(path) 
{ 
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); 
var files = new Array(); 
var fso_files = fso.GetFolder(path).Files; 
for(i=0;i<fso_files.length;i++) 
{ 
var filePath = fso_files[i].path; 
if(filePath.substring(filePath.length-4,filePath.length).toLowerCase()=="html") 
files.push(fso_files[i].path); 
} 
}

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: First, you should edit your question and add the code to it, properly formatted (code is very difficult to read in comments). Second, you have to explicitly explain what you mean by "does not work". What does it do and what do you expect it to do.

Answer (score -1):

simply you can't read file system by javascript, you have to use a server side programming language.

Comment: how is the "server side programming language" going to read files form a client (JavaScript is a client side language) ?

Comment: i am saying he should read the files using c# for example, no javascript involved

Comment: And i am saying ... how is the OP going to use a server side language to read files from a client ?