# Display current directory of local HTML page in text box on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vbscript

I have an HTML page located in local drive path:
C:\Data Export Tool\Daily Report\DisplayData.html

When I open this HTML page I want the HTML path in a text box like 'C:\Data Export Tool\Daily Report'
How to accomplish this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818576/get-directory-of-a-file-name-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can use window.location: [www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) in order to get this value on js.

```
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById("textBoxId").value = window.location;
}
```